# How can I code a Conditional phase shift transform?

Tags: quantum-gate, q#

I am interested in implementing a operation in Q#. The operation should follow the algorithm below:
[image: Taken from a paper on quantum algorithms]

When $A=0$ it is quite easy to see that the algorithm states if the qubitt is in nullspace apply a transformation to flip the sign of the qubit.

I am not sure how to use the algorithm for the 'i is in A' case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to define a new operation whose unitary representation is
\begin{align}
    S_a|i\rangle = \begin{cases}
        -|i\rangle \text{ if } i = a \\
         |i\rangle \text{ otherwise }
    \end{cases}.
\end{align}

At that point, $S_A = \prod_{a \in A} S_a$.
In Q#, you can implement $S_a$ easily using the `ControlledOnInt` operation, an auxillary qubit in the $|-\rangle$ state, and an `X` operation:

```
operation ApplyConditionalPhase(subset : Int[], register : LittleEndian)
: Unit is Adj + Ctl {
    using (aux = Qubit()) {
        within {
            // prepare aux in the |−⟩ state. 
            H(aux);
            Z(aux);
        } apply {
            for (element in subset) {
                (ControlledOnInt(element, X))(register!, aux);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works using the same **phase kickback** principle as in the Deutsch−Jozsa algorithm; for more details on how phase kickback works, check out Chapters 6 and 7 of [my book](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-quantum-computing-with-python-and-q-sharp?a_aid=learn-qc-granade&a_bid=ee23f338).

Comment: What does setting our data type to LittleEndian for our register input do?

Comment: Also, why do we specify the output is Adj + Ctl?

Comment: The `LittleEndian` user-defined type (UDT)_is used to specify that a register of qubits is to be interpreted as encoding an unsigned integer; in this case, that ensures that the user passes in the control register in a format consistent with the ordering expected by `ControlledOnInt`.

For your other question, `is Adj + Ctl` specifies that the operation is adjointable and controllable, so that you can implement $S_A^{\dagger}$ and controlled applications of $S_A$ automatically.

Comment: last question: what does apply do? can we replace that line by using ApplytoAll or ApplytoEach and containing it into the for loop?

Comment: The `within`/`apply` block first applies the contents of the `within` block, then the `apply` block, then the adjoint of the `within` block, making it easy to write $U^{\dagger}VU$-style patterns. In principle, you could write this using `ApplyToEach`, but you'd run into the slight difficulty that the thing you want to loop over is the `element` input to `ControlledOnInt`, not an input of the return value of `ControlledOnInt`. That means you'd need a second operation (likely marked with the `internal` keyword) that directly takes `element` as an input to use `ApplyToEach` here.

Comment: Oh very cool, I will definitely bear in mind LittleEndian, it will help a lot with my project. Is there encoding for the proper set of integers built into q#? Ok that makes alot of sense in regards to Adj+Ctl. Would you then say it is good practice to apply Adj+Ctl to any quantum gate that is user defined?

Comment: Most all of the integer support in the Q# standard and numerics libraries is provided by the [`Microsoft.Quantum.Arithmetic` namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arithmetic), such that the reference docs for that namespace can be a great place to start.

For `is Adj + Ctl`, there are cases where you may not want to use that, such as when your operation has an internal measurement, or when your operation returns an output; short of that, it's a good practice to add those characteristics when you can to help increase the generality of your code

Comment: I have been treating my user defined gates as something that is output-ed from my operation{}. I am understanding that based on your code and what you have said I must not do this so I can utilize Adj+Ctl. Please let me know if I am missing the mark. In short, your advice so far has been very helpful. Q# is fairly new to me and I am enjoying digging through the depths, it is great to have your knowledge as a resource. Thank you Chris.

Comment: Happy to help, thanks for all your great questions! With respect to user-defined operations, I don't think its wrong to return operations as outputs at all; indeed, that's how the `ControlledOnInt` function works to give a similar experience to the `Controlled` keyword. If you're interested in learning more about Q#, the new [Learn module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/qsharp-create-first-quantum-development-kit/) may be of interest, along with https://docs.microsoft.com/quantum and my book at bit.ly/qsharp-book.

Comment: Past that, the qsharp.community project maintains a great list of resources at https://qsharp.community/resources/. You may also find the resources at https://project-awesome.org/ebraminio/awesome-qsharp to be helpful. There's lots of good material out there to help you as you explore Q#! 

Comment: Speaking of qsharp.community, we are always looking for posts and content from folks so if you are interested in writing something about what you learned here or anything else  you think other community members might find useful, let use know!  https://qsharp.community/blog/call-for-contributions/

You can see an example of a post we just got today on the Q# + Python install process for Linux: https://qsharp.community/blog/qsharp-python-linux/

Answer (score 0):

```
operation ApplyConditionalPhase_0(register: LittleEndian) : Unit is Adj + Ctl
{
    using (aux = Qubit()) 
    {
        (ControlledOnInt(0,X))(register!,aux);
    }
}
operation ApplyConditionalPhase(register : LittleEndian) : Unit is Adj + Ctl 
{
    using (aux = Qubit()) 
    {
        (ControlledOnInt(1,X))(register!,aux);
    }
}
```

I realized this paper treats A as all positive integers, that means not including zero. I am understanding this gate to simply flip the qubit when it is 0 for the first. Since 0 is not in the set of positive integers, we flip all qubits that are 1 to satisfy i = a.